# Splunk - Table to display count > 1 and an additional field?

Tags: splunk

I am trying to generate a search where it scans “mylogs” and isolates only IDs that appear in more than one LOCATION.  I’m getting close with the following search:

mylogs | stats count by ID | where count > 1 | table ID, LOCATION

This isolates IDs that appear more than once, but does not list the LOCATIONS of these IDs.

I’ve explored dc; using charts vs. tables, trying to eval the count, count AS newfield, but all to no avail.  Thinking this isn’t rocket science.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it.

```
mylogs 
| stats count, values(LOCATION) as LOCATION by ID 
| where count > 1 
| mvexpand LOCATION 
| table ID, LOCATION
```

When you use `stats count by id` you lose all other fields except count and id. Whenever you use stats, always include all the fields you will need for displaying or further processing. Hence, `values(LOCATION)` is used to gather all the locations seen for the ID. This however will create a multivalue field which is why I split each location for an ID using mvexpand.